# Library which implements messaging system to transfer events in C++

Tags: library, c++

In our Desktop project for debian we need a lightweight and fast library event/message system.

So, we have application with architecture "Model View Presenter". And we need a lightweight and fast library for communication between layers Model->Presenter and View->Presenter.

We don`t need a library based on sockets, some slow like dbus, only light and preferable header only. Thread safety is also must be implemented in that library. Any suggestion?

Comment: You think that Dbus is slow? On what grounds? And can you tell us how quick the solution needs to be?

Answer (score 2):

## ZeroMQ

I would recommend you to look at [ZeroMQ](http://zeromq.org) library. It is a tiny library with support of C++ programming language, as well, it is quite stable, have a wide community and easy to use. It contains an [inproc](http://api.zeromq.org/2-1:zmq-inproc) transport especially designed to pass messages between threads in a single process application.